# How can I reference theme colors in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, themes

Working in Kotlin on Android Studio 2021.2.1, for a `themes.xml` file like this:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.ChordTrainer" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#888888</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
...
```

In class code, I can reference the `colorPrimary` color and use it to do something like draw a filled rectangle like this:

```
fun drawRect(iv:ImageView) {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(iv.width, iv.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

    val paint = Paint()
    paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
    paint.strokewidth = 1f

    val typedValue = TypedValue()
    context.theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValue, true)
    paint.color = typedValue.data
    canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, 20f, 20f, paint)
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
}
```

I'd like to be able to similarly reference the `colorOnPrimary` color from `themes.xml`, but the `android.R.attr.colorOnPrimary` resource ID doesn't exist. Any ideas on how I could reference it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better to use the most obvious way for this, you can just move the `colorOnPrimary` to `colors.xml`

```
<color name="colorOnPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Then you can use the color reference in the `themes.xml`

```
<item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorOnPrimary</item>
```

And in the code

```
paint.color = context.getColor(R.color.colorOnPrimary)
```

Comment: colorOnPrimary in themes.xml is dynamic such that it will reference a different color whether the device is in dark mode or not. I want to take advantage of that feature of themes.xml. Referencing an item in colors.xml won't have the same effect, but that makes me think...maybe I can create 2 colors.xml that work like themes.xml. I'll try that.

Comment: I kind of found my answer. For what I'm doing, colorBackground will work and android.R.attr.colorBackground is accessible. That doesn't answer why I can't access android.R.attr.color.colorOnPrimary, however.

Comment: For the night theme, you can just add `colors.xml` to `value-night` res folder with the value of the color for the theme.
As you see the use of `android.R.attr.color` can have an unexpected result. Moreover, Google can change (rename, remove or deprecate) the attribute in the future, so it's better if you won't depend on this.
if you still need it try this `MaterialColors.getColor(this, R.attr.colorOnPrimary)`

Comment: Thanks sergpetrov! 2 different colors.xml's sounds like the best solution. Getting the color using MaterialColors.getColor answers my initial question directly.

Answer (score 0):

In xml, you can access your primary/secondary/tertiary etc. colors from the resource files using this construction: `android:color="?attr/colorPrimary"`, just change the color type to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

[image]    [![Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 or Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1

```
 1. color.xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#1bade3</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#1bade3</color>
</resources>

 2. themes.xml file 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.MsgShareApp" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>][1]][1]
```